# How to register Spring Context Events for current test ApplicationContext at runtime

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit, junit5

**Background**:

My goal is to collect various timestamps while executing JUnit 5 tests in a Spring environment to create a statistic of the durations of the different tasks. ([Repository for reference](https://github.com/adessoAG/junit-insights.git))

Because I can't touch the actual test code, I have to register callbacks like the [ContextRefreshedEvent](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/event/ContextRefreshedEvent.html) from within my JUnit Jupiter extension. Currently I am registering [these callbacks](https://github.com/adessoAG/junit-insights/blob/master/library/src/main/kotlin/de/adesso/junitinsights/spring/SpringCallbacks.kt) in a [Spring configuration object](https://github.com/adessoAG/junit-insights/blob/master/library/src/main/kotlin/de/adesso/junitinsights/spring/InsightConfiguration.kt) and hope that this is found by some component scan in the test application. As you can imagine this does not work reliably for every test context.

**Problem**:

I hope that I can somehow register these events like the ContextRefreshedEvent manually in [my first callback method from JUnit](https://github.com/adessoAG/junit-insights/blob/master/library/src/main/kotlin/de/adesso/junitinsights/junit/JUnitCallbacks.kt#L39). As far as I understand, this requires me to add either a Configuration or a Component containing the callbacks to the currently running Spring Context at runtime.

Is that possible or do you know any other solution to my initial problem? I would really appreciate any input you have on this issue because I am working on this for quite a while now.

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update**:

Spring Framework 5.2 will have built-in support for test events. See [GitHub issue 18490](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/18490) for details.

---

The best way to fire test-related events in a Spring `ApplicationContext` is to implement a custom (Spring) `TestExecutionListener` that fires the events via the `ApplicationEventPublisher` API (which `ApplicationContext` implements).

You can access the test's `ApplicationContext` within lifecycle methods in your custom `TestExecutionListener` via `TestContext#getApplicationContext()`.

To avoid having to touch test code, you can have Spring automatically register your custom `TestExecutionListener`, as described here: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.1.4.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/testing.html#testcontext-tel-config-automatic-discovery

Your custom `TestExecutionListener` will then be automatically applied to all tests run via the Spring TestContext Framework -- unless a given test class is configured to override the default listeners (e.g., via `@TestExecutionListeners(...)`).

For related discussion, see the following Spring JIRA issues:

- https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-8710
- https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-13916

Regards,

Sam (author of the *Spring TestContext Framework*)

Comment: The `TestExecutionListener` interface only provides test related callbacks. However, I would like to also listen for `ContextRefreshedEvent`. I can't figure out how to add listeners for these events to the application context I get from the other callbacks. Simply adding [my bean](https://github.com/adessoAG/junit-insights/blob/master/library/src/main/kotlin/de/adesso/junitinsights/spring/SpringCallbacks.kt) to the context [via registerBeanDefinition()](https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-core/bean-definition.html) does not seem to work.

Comment: You will need to configure your bean in the test's `ApplicationContext` _before_ the testing framework loads the `ApplicationContext` -- for example, via an `@Bean` method if you're using JavaConfig.

Comment: How can I do that without touching the test code? The callbacks from the `TestExecutionListener` are all triggered after the testing framework loads, right? I only know how to use the `@Bean` annotation inside a configuration class which would require me to change the test code, doesn't it? Thank's a lot for your support!

Comment: If you cannot introduce new `@Bean` methods in a `@Configuration` class loaded via the test configuration, you can implement a `org.springframework.test.context.ContextCustomizer` to register beans programmatically.

Comment: See the Javadoc for `org.springframework.test.context.ContextCustomizerFactory` for details on how to register your own customizer.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Thanks a lot for the support, this worked perfectly for me! For everyone wondering how my solution looks like, have a look at [this Pull Request](https://github.com/adessoAG/junit-insights/pull/116)

Comment: FYI: events will be supported out of the box in Spring Framework 5.2. I'll update my answer accordingly. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/18490