# How to get callback in Junit 5 *before* Spring test context is loaded?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit5

I'm using a Junit 5 extension to start up a Wiremock server, before any tests run. However, one of the beans in the Spring context makes a remote call as part of its initialization, which I can't change, and that call results in a ConnectionException because the Wiremock server hasn't started yet.

How do I configure my JUnit 5 test to get a callback *before* Spring loads the text context?

My JUnit 5 extension looks like this:

```java
public class MyWiremockExtension implements BeforeAllCallback, AfterAllCallback {

  private final WireMockServer wireMock = new WireMockServer(...);
  
  @Override
  public void beforeAll(ExtensionContext extensionContext) throws Exception {
    wireMock.start();
  }

  @Override
  public void afterAll(ExtensionContext extensionContext) throws Exception {
    wireMock.stop();
  }
}
```

The Spring Bean config is buried deep in upstream code that my OkHttpClient bean depends on, but it looks something like this:

```java
@Configuration
public class OkHttpClientConfiguration {

  @Bean
  OkHttpClient okHttpClient(...) {
    OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()...build();
    // wrap the okHttpClient in OAuth handling code which eagerly fetches a token
  }
}
```

My test looks like this:

```java
@SpringBootTest(properties = {...})
@ExtendWith(MyWiremockExtension.class)
class MyTest {
...
}
```

The closest answer I've found so far is [How to register Spring Context Events for current test ApplicationContext at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54114640/how-to-register-spring-context-events-for-current-test-applicationcontext-at-run), but that doesn't provide a callback method for *before* the test context loads.

My best guess about how to do this is either:

1. create my own `ContextCustomizerFactory`, or
2. extend `SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper`, override `buildTestContext()` to start wiremock before calling `super.buildTestContext()`, then `@BootstrapWith` my class instead of Spring Boot's, though I'm not sure which callback I'd use to stop the wiremock server.

Answer (score 1):

what worked for me in a similar case:

created a own Annotation and specify the extensions there

```
@Inherited
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@ExtendWith(
    {
        MyWiremockExtension.class,
        SpringExtension.class,
    }
)
public @interface WireMockSpringTest {
```

this preserves the order in my case

Comment: OK that works great, thanks! The only minor problem I've got is that my `@SpringBootTest` annotation is actually setting several test `properties`, so I can't completely ditch that annotation and replace it with `@ExtendWith({MyWiremockExtension.class, SpringExtension.class})`.

Comment: No worries, I just added that part. I didn't include it in my original question because I didn't want to include unimportant details, sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what worked for me:

- Implement it with the Spring TestContext framework, this also makes it work with TestNG
- implement `TestExecutionListener`
- make the test execution listener implement `Ordered`
- implement `getOrder` and return a value less than 2000 (order of DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener)

Sample code https://github.com/marschall/spring-test-scope/blob/master/src/main/java/com/github/marschall/spring/test/scope/TestScopeTestExecutionListener.java

Comment: Have you tried using that with Spring Boot? How does that work if I'm using `SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper`, e.g.?

Comment: @SteveK I have not tried it with Spring Boot.